# Why won't Google Plus automatically upload all photos and videos?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I'm using an Android Phone by LG. Model #LG-D520. It's known as the OPTIMUS F3Q. I want Google Plus to automatically upload every photo and video that I record.

My Auto-backup options for photos are Wifi+Cellular. My auto-backup options for videos are Wifi-Only.

This morning I took 5 photos and 1 video. I am currently sitting in my home connected to my Wifi network for the past several hours. Yet only 2 photos have been uploaded. It doesn't seem to be uploading the video or the other photos? Why? How to work-around this bug?

This problem in such a basic operation is very frustrating. It has plagued me for several months and I have seen other people complaining about it in other forums.﻿

Comment: How do you know it didn't upload the media? Are you looking at [highlights](https://plus.google.com/photos) or [all photos](https://plus.google.com/photos/yourphotos)?

Answer (score 2):

It helped me to uncheck and check again the option "Back Up all" on the phone. It sort of restarts the process of backing up. But now they aggressively forced everyone to switch to Google Photos, so this will work differently.

Answer (score 1):

Give it more time. I find sometimes it can be quite slow at uploading. The fact that two photos have been uploaded shows that it is working. Be patient.

Comment: It's still stuck on two photos more than a day later.